# How to use join to fetch related data from many tables?

Tags: mysql, join

table name: **holi**

- id
- country
- hdate (holiday date)
- description
- link

and the above table is split into many tables to reduce redundancy

as table **countries**

- id
- name

table **holidays**

- id
- holiday

table **holiday_countries**

- id
- holiday_id (fk of id from holidays)
- country_id (fk of id from countries)
- link

SO now i need to get the hdate from table **holi** and id in **holiday_countries**

the id from holiday_conuntries can be fetched by relating the values of holi table with all the other tables..

description from holi table related to the holiday from holidays table
country from holi table related to the country from countries table

How can i get that?

Comment: Your FK relationships are not clear, can you indicate those?

Comment: holiday_id from holiday_countries is fk of id from holidays , country_id from holiday_countries is fk of id from countries. Actually i've another table with the columns as hid,year,date.. I want to insert into this table using select from all the other tables..(hid should be the id from holiday_countries, hdate from holi)

Comment: I have 7580 rows in holi table and i tried the following query but it listed 7638 rows.. I dont know where i'm doing wrong

the query is select holiday_countries.id , year(holi.hdate), holi.hdate from holi left join holidays on holi.description = holidays.holiday left join countries on holi.country=countries.name left join holiday_countries on holidays.id = holiday_countries.holiday_id and countries.id = holiday_countries.country_id

Comment: What relationship does `holi` have with any of the other tables?

Comment: the table holi does not have any relationship with others.. i'm splitting  the table holi to all other tables.. So i need to transfer data from the old table to the new table

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are matching so this might be a bit off but I would put:

```
SELECT * 
FROM holi
JOIN holidays AS h
ON holi.description = h.holiday
JOIN countries AS c 
ON holi.country = c.name
```

Where the `SELECT *` can be replaced with whatever you want to select.

Comment: I have 7580 rows in holi table and i tried the following query but it listed 7638 rows.. I dont know where i'm doing wrong the query is select holiday_countries.id , year(holi.hdate), holi.hdate from holi left join holidays on holi.description = holidays.holiday left join countries on holi.country=countries.name left join holiday_countries on holidays.id = holiday_countries.holiday_id and countries.id = holiday_countries.country_id

Comment: Maybe try a left join instead of a join. Right now it would be generating every possible combination.

Comment: Look at the above comment, its a left join only